# How to retrieve users comments and ratings for an app in Android store?

Tags: android, google-play

I'm trying to retrieve users comments and average rating for a particular app? is there any API provided or repository for this purpose? or I should crawl the google play?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no documented and supported API for this.

Comment: So you think I should do that manually?

Comment: I'm thinking that you should just read them.